# C++ using templates to create methods for specific enum values

Tags: c++, templates, enums

I'd like to write one method and have the compiler generate multiple methods based on specific enum values.

Below I have some isValid*() methods. They all have the same structure as you can see, so I would like to combine them into one method. Maybe templates would be useful for this? Maybe not.

Something like this pseudo code (Edited for clarity):

```
enum Dir { East, West, South, North }

bool isValidFromWest(const Dir dir)
{
  switch (dir)
  {
    case West:    return foo(dir);
    case East:    return true;
    case North:   return false;
    case South:   return false;
  }
}

bool isValidFromEast(const Dir dir)
{
  switch (dir)
  {
    case East:    return foo(dir);
    case West:    return true;
    case North:   return false;
    case South:   return false;
  }
}

bool isValidFromSouth(const Dir dir)
{
  switch (dir)
  {
    case South:   return foo(dir);
    case North:   return true;
    case West:    return false;
    case East:    return false;
  }
}

bool isValidFromNorth(const Dir dir)
{
  switch (dir)
  {
    case North:   return foo(dir);
    case South:   return true;
    case West:    return false;
    case East:    return false;
  }
}
```

Is there a compile time way to combine these methods into a single method that maintains performance and does not sacrifice too much code clarity.

Comment: Maybe you should look into a lookup table and function objects (or a `std::map` and function objects).

Comment: I don't think you understand how templates work. They don't work with a specific value, they work with a specific type. Also, what's with `opposite(TDIR)`, you can't pass in the name of the type to a function it is like calling `doSomething(int)`.

Comment: @HSchmale There is such a thing as a non-type template parameter.

Comment: You can indeed template on an integer value, not just a type.

Comment: @T.C. I feel like that's bad practice. It just is a non standard way of working with templates or a least one that I haven't seen before. Now that the poster has clarified it makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template is useful in such case and the following code may meet your requirement.

To make it simpler, It is neccessary to manually change the values of `enum Dir` to some special values(sum of two opposite directions is zero).

```
enum Dir{East = -2, West = 2, South = -1, North = 1};

bool foo(const Dir dir)
{
    //Do something
    return false;
}

template< Dir n >
struct CalDir
{
    static bool isValid(const Dir dir)
    {
        switch (dir)
        {
        case n:     return foo(dir);
        case 0 - n: return true;
        default:    return false;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Dir a = East;
    CalDir<East>::isValid(a); //Equivalents to isValidFromWest(a)
    Dir b = North;
    CalDir<South>::isValid(b);//equivalents to isValidFromSouth(b)

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Template slection happening on top of types passing to the template function/user defined type and not depends on values such as enum.

If you just want to switch over Enum, you don't need template and code will be as follows:

```
#include<iostream> 
enum Dir { East, West };


void doStuff()
{
    std::cout<<"doStuff"<<std::endl;
}
// This method should be resolved at compile time
void  opposite()
{
   std::cout<<"Opposite"<<std::endl;
}



void  isValid(const Dir dir)
{
  switch (dir)
  {
    case East:
       doStuff();
    case West:
        opposite();

  }
}
int main()
{
    isValid(East);
    return 0;
}
```